# communication between android and fpga board

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, fpga

I am trying to transfer data from my android device to FPGA board. The android device supports the USB host mode and the connected FPGA board uses RS_232 port. So I got a USB-RS232 converter device(CP210x) for the connection. I coded the transfer as mentioned on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements View.OnClickListener, Runnable {

private static final String TAG = "TransferData";

private Button sendB;
private UsbManager mUsbManager;
private UsbDevice mDevice;
private UsbDeviceConnection mConnection;
private UsbEndpoint mEndpointIntr;
private static final char DATA = 'A';
static UsbDevice device;
static int TIMEOUT = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    sendB.setOnClickListener(this);

    mUsbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.d(TAG, "intent: " + intent);
    String action = intent.getAction();

    device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
        setDevice(device);
    } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
        if (mDevice != null && mDevice.equals(device)) {
            setDevice(null);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void setDevice(UsbDevice device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setDevice " + device);
    if (device.getInterfaceCount() != 1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "could not find interface");
        return;
    }
    else Log.w(TAG, "found interface");
    UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
    // device should have one endpoint
    if (intf.getEndpointCount() == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "could not find endpoint");
        return;
    }
    else Log.w(TAG, "found endpoint");
    // endpoint should be of type interrupt

    Log.w("endpoint", "" + intf.getEndpointCount());
    UsbEndpoint ep = intf.getEndpoint(1);
    if (ep.getType() != UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "endpoint is not interrupt type");
        return;
    }
    else Log.w(TAG, "endpoint is interrupt");
    mDevice = device;
    mEndpointIntr = ep;
    if (device != null) {
        UsbDeviceConnection connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);
        if (connection != null && connection.claimInterface(intf, true)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "open SUCCESS");
            mConnection = connection;
            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "open FAIL");
            mConnection = null;
        }
     }
}

private void sendCommand(char control) {
        if (mConnection != null) {
            byte[] message = new byte[1];
            message[0] = (byte)control;
            // Send command via a control request on endpoint zero
            UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
            UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(1);
            mConnection.claimInterface(intf,true);
            int res =  mConnection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, message, message.length, TIMEOUT);
            Log.w("data sent","result " + res);
        }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == sendB) {
        sendCommand(DATA);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
    UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
    request.initialize(mConnection, mEndpointIntr);
    byte status = -1;
        request.queue(buffer, 1);
        // send poll status command
        sendCommand(DATA);
        // wait for status event
        if (mConnection.requestWait() == request) {
            byte newStatus = buffer.get(0);
            if (newStatus != status) {
                Log.d(TAG, "got status " + newStatus);
                status = newStatus;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "requestWait failed, exiting");
        }
}
```

I get success in opening device and I get send result as 1. But no data received is reflected as the FPGA board. What am I doing wromg?

Comment: Do you have a driver for the USB to RS232 that works? Because just opening a USB only gives you access to the controller on that unit and nothing else.

Comment: That seems to be the problem then. I have Linux drivers for the device, but to push it to the the android device seems to be a tough job. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @FarhadA - the method utilized here does not involve a "driver" - instead the USB operations are directly accomplished from the userspace code of the application.  Conceptually, Android handles USB host a lot like how libusb on the desktop works, and not according to the kernel-driver type of scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch RX with TX on FPGA. Did other communcation work with this connection?
Is there a design on the FPGA which will serve the UART?